# Updating service role in CodeBuild doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I want to update the service role of a code build project. I create the role using the following CLI commands from inside another **CodeBuild** project

```
aws iam create-role --role-name Code-Build-Service-Role --path /service-role/ --assume-role-policy-document file://codebuild-servicerole-policies.json
```

The assume role policy document looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

It is successfully able to create the role.

After this I run the `update-project` command to update the service role

```
aws codebuild update-project --name "MyCodeBuild" --service-role **ARN From The Previous Step**
```

This gives the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the UpdateProject operation: CodeBuild is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on **ARN From The Previous Step**
```

However if I run the `aws codebuild update-project` only in a separate build, the service role gets attached to the CodeBuild project from `create-role` step.